Docker is not running In windows Standard User throwing Error. How To Resolve the Issue
I download the docker for windows 11 and i installed. after installation i try to open the docker its throwing ERROR: open .\pipe\docker_engine_linux: The system cannot find the file specified.
I need perfect solution to resolve this issue

Does this answer your question? Error response from daemon: open \.\pipe\docker_engine_linux: The system cannot find the file specified


click Windows + R.
type "netplwiz"
select your username and double-click.
Go to Group membership
Select Others and Choose docker-users
Restart the computer

